# Rewrite htaccess rule for different Url

Tags: javascript, php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have url `public/l/img/logo.png` and i want to look at `public/img/logo.png` using htaccess in my public directory.

I tried using this but it doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^l/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

My present htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my public is real directory
Thanks in advance

Comment: By "public is real directory" you actually mean it's the DOCUMENT_ROOT? See also [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9153262)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:** If `public` is a real directory then use this rule in `/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/public/

RewriteRule ^l/(.+)$ $1 [NC,L]
```

**Case 2:** If `public` is a NOT a real directory then use this rule in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/public/l/(.+)$ public/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i am getting 404 error upon adding it to my htaccess

Comment: Not enough information. Which of these 2 versions you used and what **full URL** did you enter in browser?

Comment: i used the first version , i am getting 404 error when i have l in url

Comment: Did you place that .htaccess in `/public/` directory? And I repeat **what full URL did you enter in browser**?

Comment: yeahm used full url like localhost/user/public/l/assets/images/spy.png causing 404 but if remove "l" from url it is working fine

Comment: See that is the information hidden so far in your question so far. Check my updated answer now